# Spaces in textfield from text-variable: php+html

Tags: php, html, spaces

i have a strange problem... I'm getting string-data from db:

```
$siteDesc = strval( $configHandle->getConfigValue( 'SITE_DESCRIPTION' ) ); 
var_dump( $siteDesc );
```

It returns:

> string(19) "Some description..."

But in code:

```
<input type="field" name="site_desc" value="<?=$siteDesc;?>" />
```

There is a lo of spaces in textfield before text:

"           Some description..."

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have a linebreak in there, but that would usually account only for one whitespace

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you trim the value before inserting it in the text field?

```
<input type="field" name="site_desc" value="<?=trim($siteDesc);?>" />
```